# Blank screen in codeigniter while running the process

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, loading

I am developing a php script using codeigniter framework. My script is performing a heavy data loading process at the beginning of the script. I have used a gif in order to avoid displaying a blank screen for user until it completes the backend process. However,  I noticed the gif I have used within the view won't display until all of the other processes are completed which is useless.

Is there anyway that I can run a preloading screen until other processes are completed?  If so how can I do this?

I tried adding the page which contains gif at the top (before running all of the other processes) But still no luck,  it loads everything along with the other views only.

Thanks in advance

MY CODE AS FOLLOWS,

**SCRIPT**

```js
 <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
        //alert("IN");
        $.ajax({
        method :'GET',
        url: baseUrl+'main/LoadAllitems',
        //type: "GET",
        success:function(data){
        $('.se-pre-con').hide();
        $('#renderer').html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```html
public function LoadAllitems()
 {

  $MenuData['searches']=$this->get_search_form_data();
  $MenuData['dailydeals']=$this->get_daily_deals_data();
  //$MenuData['monthlydeals']=$this->get_monthly_deals_data();
  //$MenuData['featuredproducts']=$this->get_featured_products_data();

  $response=$this->load->view('includes/search',$MenuData,TRUE);
  echo $response;
  $response2=$this->load->view('homepage/dailydeals',$MenuData);
  echo $response2;
  //$this->load->view('homepage/mainslider',$MenuData);
  //$this->load->view('homepage/monthlydeals',$MenuData);
  //$this->load->view('homepage/feature',$MenuData);
  //$this->load->view('homepage/subscribe',$MenuData);
  //$this->load->view('main',$MenuData);

 }
```

**INDEX**

```html
public function index()
 {
    $this->load->view('main',$MenuData);
  }
```

Comment: it's cannot be done if using only PHP, because your gif is loaded using server side..

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427759/showing-a-progress-wheel-while-page-loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the page initially with the gif then when the page loaded. run a script that request an ajax call to request the data you needed. btw we can help lot more if you provide your code: view and controller.

> SampleController.php

```
function index()
{
   $this->load->view('init_view');
}

function ajax_load_data()
{
   ...
   $response = $this->load->view('some_view',$data,TRUE);
   echo $response;
}
```

> init_view.php

```
<div id="loading">SOMEGIF</div>
<div id="renderer"></div>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
             method : 'get',
             url    : '<?php echo site_url("samplecontroller/ajax_load_data");?>'
             success: function(responce){
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#renderer').html(responce);
                 }   
         })

   })

</script>
```

> some_view.php

```
<h1><?= $title ?></h1>
<p><?= $intro ?></p>
```

Comment: @reyenz :  Thanks for your answer. my all view load functions are within the controllet index function. and currently I'm loading them all when page loads. so according to your solution can I add all these views to another function and call that function through ajax?  Please refer my code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51152623/9407925

Comment: Basically you have your initial view on Controller:index then you perform an ajax call after it loads as what my answer shown. From the ajax where you call your Controller:anotherMethod. that anotherMethod have a separate view that intakes the data. ill update my answer to help you more.

Comment: Okay , i will try as you have advised, but one more question "$response = $this->load->view('some_view',$data,TRUE);
   echo $response;" instead of doing like this cant i just do like this within the ajax_load_data()>>$this->load->view('some_view',$data); if not could you please tell me why? Thanks a lot

Comment: Its because your passing the view into a variable as a string in which you will pass over the ajax call.

Comment: Oh Okay Thanks , let me try this and get back to you :)

Comment: i checked and loading icon starting to appear and after page loads it disappear, but content within  function ajax_load_data() won't appear.

Comment: sure, here it won't let me to post , wait i will edit my question, Please check my question now, i have edited the question

Comment: Okay, It works, Thanks a lot, i haven't added the <div id="renderer"></div>, that was the issue, and 1 more question ,how can i use ajax query only for my main page load? without using inline script , because i will be having my js files on a separate file. is there anyway to detect the page ? for this function ->  $(document).ready(function(){}